JavaScript Metaplex - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
I installed metaplex (latest, down to 0.8.10) in a new Vite React app (TypeScript), and when using the createUmi function, it is erroring out with:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

var streamDestructionSupported = "destroy" in import_stream.default.Readable.prototype;
Code:
const umi = createUmi("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com");
Any idea's on why and how to fix this?

can you share the full code snippets including the imports

I'm experiencing the same issue. Have you got a solution?

Could you create a new question @Luke adding your imports and versions and a small code snippet causing the error

Metaplex uses stream which is a node js core module (Used to be polyfilled by default in webpack < 5). You will need to manually polyfill stream in your project to get the library working in the browser.
